# UserControl does not save values after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a UserControl in a Gridview with a textbox. The textbox is populated by a database call and then it can be edited by the user to save another value to it. But when I try to save another value it is nothing. Code Below:

```
  public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string sql;
            sql = "select lname from clients order by lname";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString());

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }


    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl uc;
        TextBox tb;
        string name;

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {


            uc = (UserControl)row.FindControl("UserInfo1");
            tb = (TextBox)uc.FindControl("txt_name");
            name = tb.Text; 

        }


    }



}
```

}

UserControl Code:

```
public partial class UserInfo : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{ 

    public string Name {get;set;}

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txt_name.Text = Name;


    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string name;

        name = this.txt_name.Text;



    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `UserControl` code. You are setting the text every time, postback or not, to be the value of the `Name` property.

You need to do this instead:

```
if(!IsPostback)
 txt_name.Text = Name;
```

Comment: Every novice seems to hit the same pattern of discovering this mistake... :)